# How to set the resolution of a png in R on a Mac

Tags: r, macos, plot, png, resolution

How to create a png with a 100 dpi resolution in R, on a Mac, by the `png` function?

I try:

```
png("1.png", res = 100)
plot(1)
dev.off()
```

On a Mac, the above code however produces a png with only 72 dpi, which can be checked *e.g.* on the command line by

```
sips -g dpiWidth 1.png
  dpiWidth: 72.000
```

Running the above R code on Windows or Unix, both results in a png with indeed the expected resolution of 100 dpi. I am aware of workarounds (using sips or ggplot), but I'd prefer the above command to work as expected on a Mac too. Am I missing something? Is there a way to (re)set the resolution of a yet existing png using R?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `width=` and `height=` ?

Comment: That has no effect: `sips` still reports 72 dpi, whatever width/height is given :-(

Comment: dpi (or ppi) is a feature of the display device, not the image.  An image has pixel dimensions.  Displaying the image on devices with different display resolutions (dpi/ppi) will result in images of different physical sizes.

Comment: Sure. But I don't want to depend on the device. I want full control on the png's width/height in inches or cm. The png function on Windows and Unix seems to do exactly what one would expect, imho. Isn't it a matter of writing the right tags (maybe https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PNG.html#PhysicalPixel) to the so-called 'image header' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Examples)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that **type = "cairo"** can do the trick!

```
png("1.png", res = 100, type = "cairo")
plot(1)
dev.off()
```

On Mac's command line one can check that the resulting resolution is indeed 100 dpi:

```
sips -g dpiWidth 1.png
  dpiWidth: 100.000
```